# C# Serial Port communication not read and send this command (include @ string)

Tags: c#, string, serial-port

i have several motor control experience with C# serial port communication..
and I receive new motor with new manufacturer..
this is first time issue with C#....

at first i tried with putty....
no issue and working good....

second i tried with hyperterminal_...
no issue and working good....

both setting follow below setting..working good

[image]

after that i try in visual C#...
this method work in several serial communication but this time failed..

```
        string COM_port = textBox20.Text.ToString();

        serialPort1 = new SerialPort();
        //  SerialPort serialPort1 = new SerialPort();

        serialPort1.PortName = COM_port;
        serialPort1.BaudRate = (int)19200; // depend on manufacturer.... NOW kss
        serialPort1.DataBits = (int)8;
        serialPort1.Parity = Parity.None;
        serialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        serialPort1.ReadTimeout = (int)5000;
        serialPort1.WriteTimeout = (int)5000;

        serialPort1.Open();

        if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            // port open success
            //Log.Warning("Chamber connection Success");
            textBox19.AppendText("Success to connect Chamber control................." + Environment.NewLine);
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
        else
        {
            // port open fail
            MessageBox.Show("Chamber connection FAIL : Please check KSS controller.");
            //Log.Warning("Chamber connection FAIL : Please check ERETEC controller.");

        }
```

when i run above code then port open success,,
so it looks no issue..
but after that below are motor moving..
below become issue...

```
             serialPort1.WriteLine("@1T100"); // move motor
            serialPort1.WriteLine("@1V25"); // setting
      
            serialPort1.WriteLine("@1STAUS");  // check status
            string receive = serialPort1.ReadLine();
            serialPort1.WriteLine("@1START");  // START MOVE
```

check status should return value but C# occur error...
without this.. last command start move should move motor but couldn't move motor..

i told you that this is no issue with hyper terminal or putty..
so i think issue is in @.
because this is first experiance that command include @.
so is there any advice to solve this issue??

thanks
Wonyong CHoi

Comment: Try by using `serialPort1.WriteLine(@"@1T00");`

Comment: `@"@1T00"` and `"@1T00"` mean exactly the same thing.

Comment: Do the machine expect any NewLine character at the end of the command?

Comment: You can't ignore the "Flow control" setting.  If you want to emulate HyperTerminal/Putty then you need to add serialPort1.Handshake = System.IO.Ports.Handshake.None;
            serialPort1.RtsEnable = true;
            serialPort1.DtrEnable = true;  But high odds that the motor controller actually uses Handshake.RequestToSend;